# Docker: multiple PHP7-FPM containers on different ports

Tags: php, docker

I am playing around with Docker for my local development environment. My setup for now is 5 containers (1 HaProxy + 2 NGINX + 2 PHP7-FPM).

The proxy container is used to direct the request based on the url, so if I enter `http://project1.dev` it will proxy the request to the `project1-nginx` that uses `project1-php` for evaluating php. The setup is similar for `http://project2.dev`.

Now, I am trying to wrap my head around the ports of the two php containers. The default fpm port is 9000, so both php containers cannot run on this. I am assuming the way to go here is to let both containers export port 9000 but make them 9000 and 9001 on the host?

Something along these lines in my compose file.

```
project_1_php:
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
project_2_php:
  ports:
    - "9001:9000"
```

So, everything boots up fine, and project 1 is working, but project 2 gives me a 502. Nginx error log says

```
2016/01/26 14:37:05 [error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) 
while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.9, server: code.dev, 
request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.17.0.4:9001"
```

Comment: Hm.. why are you "targetting" nginx server? It doesn't really make sense.. is your HAProxy between router and nginx or between nginx and fpm?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by targeting Nginx? Yes, the proxy is between the router and nginx

Comment: You're using 2 nginx servers, and each has a `server{}` block that defines `project1.dev` or `project2.dev`, and depending on that - they proxy it to appropriate `php-fpm` machine. That logic is slightly off, you don't even need HAProxy there, it's useless in that scenario. But, that's offtopic. Are you sure second `fpm` server is allowing connections from `172.17.0.9`? The default config allows connections only from localhost.

Comment: Maybe you should set the @Dracken answer as the correct ! it works for me !

Answer (score 10):

For those looking like I did for a way to run multiple NGINX and PHP-FPM containers for different projects at the same time and found this SO thread, ran across this:

https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/479

Inside the php-fpm Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm
RUN sed -i 's/9000/3001/' /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf
```

Then in your `docker-compose.yaml` file you can point your Nginx to that specific port for that PHP-FPM instance.

Comment: Working like a charm ! thanks ! maybe this should be the correct answer !

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue with php-fpm7,
as @Mjh mentioned in the comments, by default fpm listening to 127.0.0.1:9000,

so you should replace it with a 0.0.0.0:9000,

I found a solution there: [githib:matriphe/docker-alpine-nginx](https://github.com/matriphe/docker-alpine-nginx/issues/1)

So you can add to your fpm container Dockerfile :

```
RUN sed -i "s|;*listen\s*=\s*127.0.0.1:9000|listen = 9000|g" /etc/php7/php-fpm.conf
```

Answer (score -1):

Just thought I would mention that [Traefik Proxy](https://traefik.io/traefik/) is a fantastic way to handle this scenario

Comment: No because traefik only routes from the outside in.  Not internally.

Comment: I don't think you understand the assignment as your comment is not related to the question posted. https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/docker/